# Firebase child_added `this` is not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, angular, ionic2

I am developing a chat application using `Angular2, ionic2 and firebase`.
To get the chats i tried the below method

Controller code:

```
displayAllMessage() {
    let myDataRef = new Firebase("firbaseurl");
    myDataRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
      this.message = snapshot.val();
      console.log(this.message);
    });
  }
```

View Code :

```
<h1> {{message.text}} </h1>
```

but the problem here is - if I use `this.message` it is throwing the error saying `this.message` is undefined and if I use `var message` instead of `this` then it works fine. if I use `var message` then I can't display it in the view.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Use the arrow function `() => { ... }` instead of `function ()  { ... }` to retain the scope of `this.`

```
  displayAllMessage() {
    let myDataRef = new Firebase("firbaseurl");
    myDataRef.on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
      this.message = snapshot.val();
      console.log(this.message);
    });
  }
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

```
  displayAllMessage() {
    let myDataRef = new Firebase("firbaseurl");
    myDataRef.on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
      this.message = snapshot.val();
      console.log(this.message);
    }.bind(this));
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Same situation another scenario, its a issue of `(this)`. Since your `this` will refer to context of the callback function

```
...function(snapshot) {
      this.message = snapshot.val();
      console.log(this.message);
    });
```

it wont be able to find the variable message. The solution to this is pass the reference(this) to the outer method and then access it in your callback. So your code would look like.

```
displayAllMessage(parentRef : any) {
    let myDataRef = new Firebase("firbaseurl");
    myDataRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
      parentRef.message = snapshot.val();
      console.log(parentRef.message);
    });
  }
```

and call the method 
`displayAllMessage(this);` instead of `displayAllMessage();`